# How to set a property of an array of objects state in useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a useState like this:

```
  const [sortItems, setSortItems] = useState<sortedItem[]>(items);
```

And an interface sortedItem:

```
interface sortedItem {
  label: string; 
  sortingType: string;
  key: string;
}
```

items are:

```
[{key: 'name', label: 'Name', sortingType: 'initial'},
{key: 'name1', label: 'Name1', sortingType: 'initial'}]
```

I tried to change `sortingType` value of the first object in the array(as a simple example):

```
setSortItems({ ...sortItems, sortItems[0].sortingType:'another_value' });
```

but it is producing an error

Comment: Why are you mapping and then setting data inside the map?

Comment: i'm setting data in a function actually that is called inside a map. but for the sake of simplicity to post it in stackoverflow, i put it inside the map.. you can ignore the map..my issue here is in editing the property "sortyingType" of any specific object of the array

Comment: See https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set an `Object` to an `Array`. You can check out [react documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#transforming-an-array) to learn how to update an array state in the right way

Here my example code:

```js
const newSortItems = sortItems.map((item, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    return {
      ...item,
      sortingType: 'another_value',
    };
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});
setSortItems(newSortItems);
```

Solution without using `map` :

```js
const newSortItems = [...sortItems];
newSortItems.find((item, index) => index === 0 ).sortingType = 'another_value';
setSortItems(newSortItems);
```

Another solution, look simpler:

```js
const newSortItems = [
  {
    ...sortItems[0],
    sortingType : 'another_value'
  },
  ...sortItems.filter((item, index) => index !== 0)
]
setSortItems(newSortItems);
```

Comment: please see my Question edit, i want to edit it without using a map

Comment: I've updated a solution without using map

Comment: It is a great solution but i was looking for something much simpler than looping through the array

Comment: I added a new one, still looping through array but look kinda simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this .

Create a variable to hold the new sorted array ,save the sorted array in the variable

```
const newArray=sortItems.map((item,index)=>{
if(index != 0)return item;
return item.sortingType="another_value";
});
```

set this sorted array to the state

```
setSortItems(newArray);
```

Comment: How this will change the state? shouldn't the state be changed through setSortItems()?

Comment: Yes see the last line of my answer its taking the newArray and setting it using setSortItems.

Comment: please check my Question's edit, i want to update the property without using a map

Answer (score 1):

You could use the slice method.

```js
setSortItems((state) => [
  {...state[0], sortingType: "value"},
  ...state.slice(1)
]);
```

PS: Note how I've used the `state` from the `setState` callback. This helps you avoid stale closures.